# how to add an article (table) to peer-to-peer replication in sql server2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, replication, p2p, transactional-replication

I have configured peer-to-peer replication between 2 nodes. I have followed this instruction step-by-step: 
http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3814591/Peer-to-Peer-Replication-in-SQL-Server-2008-150-Configure-a-two-node-topology.htm

then I had a problem with adding new articles(new tables) to the replication. I have followed this instruction:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146867.aspx

it works, but it is not practical for an environment with many table changes.
does anyone know a better solution? I want a fast and automatic way to add articles.

UPDATE:
I have added a table to publication, just with sp_addarticle. I did not stop and start log reader agent. It seems to work. Is it going to cause problems later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is covered in [Administer a Peer-to-Peer Topology (Replication Transact-SQL Programming)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146867.aspx):

> **To add an article to an existing configuration**
>
> ```
> 1.  Quiesce the system.
>
> 2.  Execute the CREATE TABLE statement to add the new table at each node in the topology.
>
> 3.  Bulk copy the data for the new table manually at all nodes by using the bcp utility.
>
> 4.  Execute sp_addarticle to create the new article at each node in the topology. For more information, see Define an Article.
>
> After sp_addarticle is executed, replication automatically adds the article to the subscriptions in the topology.
>
> 5.  Restart the Distribution Agents at each node in the topology.
> ```

Comment: thanks about your answer. I didn't quiesce the system or restart the distribution agent, but it worked. do you think I might get in trouble for that?

Comment: If it worked and data is replicating as expected, I think you are fine.